# Watir::LI #attributes method not found

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am using [watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/) (0.6.2) on a Mac with ruby 1.9.3.  My test script finds the `<li my-attr="my-value">...</li>` element I need, but the `Watir::LI` instance does not have any of the AttributeHelper methods (`#attribute_list`, `#attributes`, `#typed_attributes`) that the documentation says should be there.  My test script needs to confirm that the `my-attr` attribute has the value `my-value`.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Is there a different way to get the attribute value, once I have the `Watir::LI` instance??

Comment: Without sample code, I'm not sure what you've tried.  Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for: `browser.li(:index => 0).attribute_value "my-attr"`

Comment: @orde, you should create it as an answer. I can delete mine since you were first by 36 seconds.

Comment: @JustinKo: No worries ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Element#attribute_value` method to get the attribute value.

For example, assuming the html

```
<li my-attr="my-value">your text</li>
```

Then the my-attr value can be retrieved by:

```
browser.li.attribute_value("my-attr")
#=> "my-value"
```